# Load more to infifnite scrolling using jQuery and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, pagination

Recently i developed a load more functionality using php and jquery . Please see my code

Html

```
<div class="container clearfix product-output">

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "result.php",
    data: { keyword:"all"}
}).done(function( msg ) {
    $( ".product-output" ).html(msg);
    $(".load-more").on("click",function(){
        var load_num= $('.load-more').length;
        var appear=[];
        $(".im-product-block").each(function(){
            appear.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "result.php",
            data: { keyword: "all", y_id: appear, load_num: load_num }
        }).done(function(msg1){
            $('.load-more-div').before(msg1);
            if($(".hide-load").val()==1){
                $(".load-more").hide();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

In `result .php` i write the db connection code and following query .

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `product` ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 15';
$query_1 = 'SELECT * FROM `product` ORDER BY id DESC';

if (ISSET($_POST['y_id'])) {
    $appear = implode("', '", $_POST['y_id']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE id NOT IN('{$appear}')  ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 15";
    $query_1 = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE id NOT IN('{$appear}') ORDER BY id DESC";
}
$result = $conn->query($query);
$result_1 = $conn->query($query_1);
$total_num = $result_1->num_rows;
echo '<div class="container clearfix product-output">';

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

        <div class="col-sm-2 im-product-block" id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">

            <p class="product-name"> <?php echo $row["name"]; ?></p></div>

    <?php }
    echo '</div>';

    if ($total_num > 15 && $_POST[load_num] == 0) {
        echo '<div class="load-more-div"><p class="load-more"> Load More</p></div>';
    }
    if ($total_num < 15) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="hide-load" class="hide-load" value="1">
<div class="load-finished"><p class="load-f"> All Products Loaded Successfully</p></div>';
    }

}
```

Here all this functionality is working fine . But instead of clicking load more button , when user scroll down to load-more it need to fetch the products automatically without clicking .

for that i using the following code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hT = $(".load-more").offset().top,
        hH = $(".load-more").outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
        $(".load-more").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

But here the execution is contunied to infinity  .It is  not stopping . Please check this code and suggest a good method

Comment: where exactly did you place your load more code. My question is similar but don't know where to place the answer. Thank you. Please help

Comment: please read this line carefully if ($total_num > 15 && $_POST[load_num] == 0) {
        echo '<div class="load-more-div"><p class="load-more"> Load More</p></div>';
    }
    if ($total_num < 15) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="hide-load" class="hide-load" value="1">
<div class="load-finished"><p class="load-f"> All Products Loaded Successfully</p></div>';
    }

Comment: Thank you for replying. i am asking where to put the answer you accepted. Can i see how you replaced it please. Again thank you for replying

Comment: How did you integrate the answer you accepted with your code above to work with ajax. I have the load more working manually but would want to automate it on scroll

Comment: could you please replace  $(".load-more").on("click",function(){ ... } with selected answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to stop your load executing while your ajax call is made and written to the page. Perhaps set a boolean variable to decide if you need to load more.

e.g.

```
var canLoad = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hT = $(".load-more").offset().top,
        hH = $(".load-more").outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && canLoad){
        canLoad = false;
        $(".load-more").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Set `canLoad` back to true once your ajax function has finished and you have loaded the data.